# any way to have a light sidebar while keeping the editor dark?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

Something like this:
[image: Something like this]

I've always liked the way Sublime Text looked and I wasn't able to reproduce this sorta theme in VS Code. Editing the workbench settings does not really achieve the same result. I end up having a light text on a slightly darker sidebar:[image: I end up having light text on a slightly darker sidebar] which is pretty hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

These will get you closer:

```
"sideBar.foreground": "#000",
"sideBar.background": "#ccc",

// "gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground": "#000",
```

You may need to modify all the gitDecoration colors to work on a light background.

I haven't figured out a way to darken the arrows for the folders yet though.  You would think they would be set by the `sidebar.foreground` property but apparently not.

And I just noticed that the `sidebar` properties also control the command palette colors!

Comment: Sry, I just realized I didn't post the settings I used to achieve the look from the screenshot: `"workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "sideBar.background": "#636774",
        "statusBar.noFolderBackground": "#343747",
        "statusBar.noFolderBorder": "#343847",
        "statusBar.background": "#343747",
        "statusBar.border": "#343747",
        "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#343747",
        "statusBar.debuggingBorder": "#343747",
        "editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground": "#343747",
    },` But the sidebar text is still light